# How to detach views in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

In Eclipse Indigo there is a *Detached* option in every tab's context menu. It's missing from Eclipse Juno. Is it possible to detach tabs in Eclipse Juno? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag the title of the views/tabs and move them with the mouse.